# How to offer custom FE plugin settings in TYPO3 7.6 extensions?

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-extensions

In general you use `flexforms` to offer custom TYPO3 plugin settings. So I've setup the following lines in my ext_tables.php:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin(
    'DS.Dscontrolpanel',
    'Dsentitymodullist',
    'Entitymodullist'
);

// ...

// Flexform
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['list']['subtypes_addlist']['dscontrolpanel_entitymodullist'] = 'pi_flexform';
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPiFlexFormValue('dscontrolpanel_entitymodullist','FILE:EXT:dscontrolpanel/Configuration/FlexForms/flexform_dscontrolpanel.xml');
```

and start a little test flexform just to test it (flexform_dscontrolpanel.xml):

```
<T3DataStructure>
<ROOT>
    <TCEforms>
        <sheetTitle>Test 1</sheetTitle>
    </TCEforms>
    <type>array</type>
    <el>
        <test>
            <TCEforms>
                <label>Test 2</label>
                <config>
                    <default>1</default>
                    <type>check</type>
                    <items type="array">
                        <numIndex index="1" type="array">
                            <numIndex index="0">enabled</numIndex>
                            <numIndex index="1">1</numIndex>
                        </numIndex>
                    </items>
                </config>
            </TCEforms>
        </test>
    </el>
</ROOT>
```

After that I cleared both the TYPO3 cache and the PHP opcode cache. But nothing happens in my FE Plugin form. Is there a new way in TYPO3 7.6+ to add custom settings to TYPO3 FE plugins or do I just miss something?

Comment: you noticed the little typo? your flexform `flexform_dsxcontrolpanel.xml` and the registered flexfom `flexform_dscontrolpanel.xml` (missing the second `x`)

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ my bad. I typed this line by my self. The file name is `flexform_dscontrolpanel.xml`. I've double checked that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have build wrong the plugin siganture.

`dscontrolpanel_dsentitymodullist` instead of `dscontrolpanel_entitymodullist`

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin(
    'DS.Dscontrolpanel',
    'Dsentitymodullist',
    'Entitymodullist'
);

// ...

// Flexform                                                                        vv
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['list']['subtypes_addlist']['dscontrolpanel_dsentitymodullist'] = 'pi_flexform';
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPiFlexFormValue(
//                  vv
    'dscontrolpanel_dsentitymodullist',
    'FILE:EXT:dscontrolpanel/Configuration/FlexForms/flexform_dscontrolpanel.xml'
);
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. So the name convention is `<extkey>_<pluginname>` in lowercase? Can I find this somewhere in the TYPO3 documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just register a frontend plugin? Then it will automatically generate  a flexform for you, which you can extend, plus it will give you this by default

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['list']['subtypes_addlist'][$pluginSignature] = 'pi_flexform';
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPiFlexFormValue($pluginSignature, 'FILE:EXT:' . $extKey . '/Configuration/FlexForms/flexform_your_extension.xml');
```

I will not change my first answer, but apparently i was wrong. Follow these steps and you ll be able to add your FlexForm:

Just in case

```
$pluginSignature = str_replace('_', '', $extKey) . '_yourextensionKey';
```

Register your FlexForm:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['list']['subtypes_addlist'][$pluginSignature] = 'pi_flexform';
```

Find your FlexForm:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPiFlexFormValue($pluginSignature, 'FILE:EXT:' . $extKey . '/Configuration/FlexForms/FlexFormNameHere.xml');
```

Comment: Which version of the Extension Builder do you use? May be it is newer than our version because we don't get this piece of code.